# How to Set animation in manifetst file to an activity

Tags: android

I am able to set animation using the `overridePendingTransition()` method to the activities through code. But I need to set animation to activity in my manifest file. I tried using themes, it's not working. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Manifest file is not designed to save animation. Your animation should be done in a xml file stored drawable rep. And then call

Comment: how can i use that animation xml in manifest file? can you give me sample code?